# how to remove or hide tree node in dev express navbar control containing treelist, using code

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

> how to remove or hide tree node in dev ex press navbar control 
>   containing treelist, using code*emphasized text*

```
 foreach (ToolStripMenuItem mi in mastersToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
            {
                if (mi.Text == "Batch")
                {
                    mastersToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Remove(mi);                       
                }
            }
```

> and

```
foreach (ToolStripMenuItem mi in mastersToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems)
            {
                if (mi.Text == "Batch")
                {
                    mi.visible=fase;                   
                }
            }
```

> both not working

Answer (score 0):

> some how got the answer

treeListMaster.Nodes[4].Nodes.RemoveAt(7);
    treeListMaster.Refresh();